# Rejoin nested fields in shopify graphql Bulk Operation query

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api-node

Is there any way to rejoin nested fields because in response, it breaks into separate objects.

**Actual Response:**

```
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746","title":"A Book bind","description":"Energize is a pure Sativa formulation designed to stimulate, excite, and keep you productive","productType":"CARTRIDGE","vendor":"ACES","totalInventory":0,"featuredImage":null,"handle":"1g-energizedurban-cart-82-89"}
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431861850","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"thc_percentage","value":"aa","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"}
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431894618","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"cbd_percentage","value":"bb","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"}
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431960154","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"strain_name","value":"Strain","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746","title":"A Book bind","description":"Energize is a pure Sativa formulation designed to stimulate, excite, and keep you productive","productType":"CARTRIDGE","vendor":"ACES","totalInventory":0,"featuredImage":null,"handle":"1g-energizedurban-cart-82-89",
metafields:[{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431861850","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"thc_percentage","value":"aa","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"},
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431894618","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"cbd_percentage","value":"bb","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"},
{"id":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Metafield\/4680431960154","namespace":"custom_fields","key":"strain_name","value":"Strain","__parentId":"gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/1755556806746"}
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shopify uses [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) (JSONL) data type to output response for bulk operations.

> Each line in the file is a node object returned in a connection. If a
>   node has a nested connection, then each child node is extracted into
>   its own object on the next line.

So, you need to go through each line and parse it as a JSON object in your script. Use the  `__parentId` attribute as a reference to a parent object.
Join it into the parent object if needed but you can only do that once response received. You can't force Shopify API to do it for you.

---

Useful links:

- [JSON Lines data type](http://jsonlines.org/)
- [The JSONL data format in Shopify](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/perform-bulk-operations-with-admin-api#the-jsonl-data-format)